# Which process was making my OS unresponsive?

Tags: performance, cpu, ram-usage

My Ubuntu system sometimes gets completely unresponsive. The mouse moves, but that's about it - no other input is registered.

I have absolutely no idea on which process is causing the system to drag and when the system becomes responsive again, the process has already ended, giving me no clues on what was happening.

Is there anyway I can posthumously check which process was making my system  drag? Is there any tool that logs processes that are using CPU / IO / RAM in real time and that we can check this log afterwards (something with a GUI would be nice).

Cheers and thank you in advance,
V

Comment: I use Conky on 14.04 and 16.04 but I've seen a really cool system monitor on 18.04 other people are using. What version of Ubuntu are you on? As far as slowing system down I usually have > 10 web pages open and it's usually a greedy page (or poorly written) that slows things down.

Comment: Cheers. I will try that out!